# R: To Fill DataFrame Column Using Lagged Data Of Itself

Tags: r

so sorry to trouble you guys.

I have a dataframe A

```
  Date       Currency Exchange TransactionNo AccountNo TransactionType Amount
  <date>     <chr>       <dbl>         <int>     <dbl> <fct>            <dbl>
1 2019-07-01 CNY         0.198       1000001     10001 Spend           -12.0 
2 2019-07-01 USD         1.35        1000002     10001 Spend            -5.31
3 2019-07-01 SGD         1           1000003     10001 Spend           -18.5 
4 2019-07-01 SGD         1           1000004     10001 Withdraw         -5.16
5 2019-07-01 SGD         1           1000005     10001 Withdraw         -5.95
6 2019-07-02 USD         1.36        1000051     10001 Spend            -8.68
```

I would like to create a new column called Balance.

The first data of Balance would be a random number between 1000 to 2000 PLUS the first data in Amount. Assuming the random number is 1000 then the first data in Balance would be 988.00 (the result of 1000 minus 12.0).
The second data of Balance should be 988.00 + the second data in Amount (-5.31) which is 982.69.
The third data of Balance should be 982.69 + the third data in Amount (-18.5) which is 964.19.
And so on.

What I am trying to do is using library(data.table) and then using the code

```
Balance := Amount + shift(Balance, 1L, type="lag")
```

Of course, my code fails to capture the fact that my first entry needs to be a random number between 1000 to 2000 PLUS the first row data in Amount.

I understand that everyone has their responsibilities in life. I have never forgotten to appreciate every single person who has spent their time and effort in helping other new programmers like me. Truly thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `shift`, just a cumulative sum (`cumsum`) of the `Amount` column.

```
A[, Balance := runif(n = 1, min = 1000, max = 2000) + cumsum(Amount)]
```

Possibly with a `by` argument.